# How to upload file in BOX Api: Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, box-api, box

I'm attempting to use the box API to upload files but I am receiving an error when executing it. Here is my code regarding the action so far

```
  public void configureBox(){
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_ID = "ID";
    BoxConfig.CLIENT_SECRET = "Secret";
    BoxConfig.REDIRECT_URL = "https://localhost";
    BoxSession session = new BoxSession(textUpload.this);
    session.authenticate(this);
    Log.i("auth","Authenticated");
  }


 Log.i("Path", absolute);
    InputStream uploadStream = new FileInputStream(
            new File("/data/user/0/com.example.emergency/files/" + summary + ".txt"));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[uploadStream.available()];
    uploadStream.read(buffer);
    String uploadName = "Doc1.txt";
    Log.i("Path", "Done");
    String destinationFolderId = "0";
    try {
        BoxRequestsFile.UploadFile request = mFileApi.getUploadRequest(uploadStream, uploadName, destinationFolderId);
        final BoxFile uploadFileInfo = request.send();
        Log.i("Success", "Uploaded " + uploadFileInfo.getName());
    } catch (BoxException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("Fail", "Failed");
    }
```

Whenever I Run this I get an error that looks like this

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.box.androidsdk.content.requests.BoxRequestsFile$UploadFile com.box.androidsdk.content.BoxApiFile.getUploadRequest(java.io.InputStream, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Any tips would be appreciated as I am stumped

Comment: mFileApi==null .

Comment: @blackapps Are you saying I should add an if statement with that?

Comment: Indeed. And then return if null. And display s toast to inform the user.